# extracting nodes values with xmlstarlet

Tags: xmlstarlet

i have this xml schema , what i want is how to extract the values of all the  nodes one by one, using XMLStarlet , in shell script

```
     <service>
        <imageScroll>
           <imageName>Photo_Gallerie_1.jpg</imageName>
        </imageScroll>
        <imageScroll>
           <imageName>Photo_Gallerie_2.jpg</imageName>
        </imageScroll>
        <imageScroll>
           <imageName>Photo_Gallerie_3.jpg</imageName>
        </imageScroll>
      </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was the solution that i found and it did perfectly the job.

```
imagescroller=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//root/services/service/imageScroll[rank_of_the_desired_item]" -v imageName -n myfile.xml
```

sorry for late.

Answer (score 15):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//imageName" -v . -n your.xml
```

output:

```
Photo_Gallerie_1.jpg
Photo_Gallerie_2.jpg
Photo_Gallerie_3.jpg
```

Is that what you needed?

- `sel` (select mode)
- `-t` (output template(this is pretty much required)
- `-m` (*for each match* of the following value)

  - `"//` (the double slash means it could be anywhere in the tree)
  - `imageName` (name of node you want)"
- `-v` (requests the value of an element in the current path) and the `.` represents current element in iteration (you could put the name of the node there but it's generally easier this way) 
  and then the
- `-n` is to add a line for every value you match.

Comment: thanks for help ; but well , that doesn't return the value that i need , for example that doesn't promote me to access to the second item. i found the solution , and i posted my response , and that works.